# How to integrate Phonon with Qt in Linux?

Tags: linux, qt, media-player, phonon

I will create a mediaplayer by using C++ and Qt 4. [Here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/phonon-overview.html#installing-phonon) it says:

> The Qt backend on Linux uses GStreamer (minimum version is 0.10),
>   which must be installed on the system. At a minimum, you need the
>   GStreamer library and base plugins.

But I can't use Phonon even I added it to .pro file. When I include `#include <phonon>` it can't find Phonon. How will I be able to use Phonon? Do I need to do any installation or something else?

Comment: The exact error messages would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you ran `configure` to install Qt, did you somehow disable Phonon support?

`-phonon` and `-phonon-backend` are enabled by default.

[Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/configure-options.html) notes:

> Phonon is built if a decent C++ compiler is used.

Are you using an up-to-date compiler?

You might try clearing your current configuration and running `configure` again:

```
make confclean
configure
```

Answer (score 0):

after installing phonon you should install libphonon-dev (if your distro is ubuntu you can find both in software center)